# is it possible to dynamically define a method's name?

Tags: python

I'm fairly fluent in C,C++,C# and Objective-C but fairly new to Python. And I'm trying things out with Python + Django. One of the first things I ran into is that if using python 2.x, "to string" functionality for Django models is done thru `__unicode__`, whereas for 3.x, it's done thru `__str__`.

I'd like to define the "to string" method in my classes only once: same body, just different signature depending on the python version.

in C and C++ for instance, this could be done via a preprocessor macro (at compile time, but it serves the purpose). In C#, via introspection, in Objective-C too (via runtime functions). But I'm not sure what the 'elegant' way to pull it off is in Python. I'v tried this so far:

```
class A(models.Model):
  def _infoMethod(self):
    # blah..

class B(models.Model):
  def _infoMethod(self):
    # blah..

# ...

class N(models.Model):
  def _infoMethod(self):
    # blah..

for c in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__], inspect.isclass):
  if callable(getattr(c[1], "_infoMethod", None)):
    setattr(c[1], '__unicode__' if sys.version_info.major < 3 else '__str__', c[1]._infoMethod)
```

And it does work, but it seems somewhat hacky that after parsing all classes I need to iterate over classes in the module, find which ones have the method and dynamically set an 'alias' to each. I'm wondering if there's a more 'meta' way about it. Something involving replacing the identifier part in the method signature in-place from within the class, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *easy* way to do this is by using a base class for all your models...

```
class ModelBase(models.Model):
    if python3:
        def __str__(self):
            return self._infoMethod()
    else:
        def __unicode__(self):
            return self._infoMethod()
```

Now just subclass that everywhere ...

```
class A(ModelBase):
    def _infoMethod(self):
        return 'foo'
```

...

and of course you *usually* don't care if you define too many methods ... You could just have `__str__` and `__unicode__` both and not worry about what Django wants to call since they're both present:

```
class ModelBase(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self._infoMethod()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self._infoMethod()
```

The other advantage here is that you don't need to alias `__str__` and `__unicode__` in all your model subclasses as some of the other answers would require -- Just do it once and you're done.

And, finally, if you don't want to keep `_infoMethod` alive, you could do something like:

```
class ModelBase(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        # I choose `unicode` here since it is a superset of __str__ ...
        return self.__str__()

class A(ModelBase):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Hello World!'
```

Comment: Why not just `def __unicode__(self): return unicode(self.__str__())` ?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid -- Because `unicode` isn't a python3.x builtin function -- And the whole point here is to make it work for both python2.x and 3.x ... And if you're gonna go that route, might as well go with `unicode(str(self))`, no?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is just

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        ...
    __str__ = __unicode__
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a class decorator:

```
def deco(cls):
    setattr(cls, '__unicode__' if sys.version_info.major < 3 else '__str__', cls._infoMethod)
    return cls

@deco
class B(models.Model):
    def _infoMethod(self):
        #blah
```

However, you could also just define the classes with `__str__ = __unicode__` and not get fancy.

Comment: @mgilson: Oops, yeah.  (Writing the code without a net on StackOverflow. . .)

Comment: seeing your example, I just went and read about class and function decorators. I like the approach, but in trying it, it seems I can't decorate a base class and have subclasses of it implicitly decorated too; I need to decorate each class. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @SaldaVonSchwartz: You could use a metaclass.  However, that is even more overkill for a simple task like this.

Comment: I marked @mgilson only because while it has the downside of leaving the `_infoMethod` alive, it does work with inheritance; otherwise I'd have to remember to add the decorator on all subclasses. But other than that, I like the decorator approach.

Comment: @SaldaVonSchwartz -- You don't _have_ to keep `_infoMethod` alive with my approach... then, rather than making an alias to `__str__` from `__unicode__`, you just have `__str__` _delegate_ to `__unicode__` by a function call (or vice-versa).

Answer (score 1):

I may not be following you exactly, but couldn't you get what you want like this?

```
class N(models.Model):
    def _infoMethod(self):

    __str__ = _infoMethod
    __unicode__ = _infoMethod
```

You have `__str__` for Python 3.x and `__unicode__` for Python 2.x, and they both are mapped to the same underlying function.